# Why does my iPhone speak certain emoji in a Japanese accent?

Tags: messages, ios, emoji, text-to-speech

My language settings are only set to English, but my iPhone speaks certain emoji (like ‍♂️ and ‍♂️) in a Japanese accent when I select them in a message and tap *Speak*. Can anyone explain? Here's a visual example of what I see when I select mixed words and emoi:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you select just the text, or just the emoji?

Comment: Hi @MattSephton. It appears that this oddity no longer occurs. My only guess is that it was a bug in that specific version of iOS. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have a non-English language selected in Speech settings?

> **Choose a voice for Speak Screen and Speak Selection**
>
> Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Speech. Enable Speak
>   Selection or Speak Screen, or both. Select Voices. Choose the one
>   voice and dialect you would like both Speak Screen and Speak Selection
>   to use.

Ref: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202362